# Solving improper integral without approximating

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I'm having trouble solving this integral in python. The function being integrated is not defined on the boundaries of integration.
I've found a few more questions similar to this, but all were very specific replies to the issue in particular.
I don't want to approximate the integral too much, if possible not at all, as the reason I'm doing this integral in the first place is to avoid an approximation.
Is there any way to solve this integral?

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
import scipy
from math import *
from scipy import integrate

m_Earth_air = (28.0134*0.78084)+(31.9988*0.209476)+(39.948*0.00934)+(44.00995*0.000314)+(20.183*0.00001818)+(4.0026*0.00000524)+(83.80*0.00000114)+(131.30*0.000000087)+(16.04303*0.000002)+(2.01594*0.0000005)
Tb0 = 288.15
Lb0 = -6.5
Hb0 = 0.0
def Tm_0(z):
    return Tb0+Lb0*(z-Hb0)
k = 1.38*10**-19 #cm^2.kg/s^2.K   #Boltzmann cst
mp = 1.67262177*10**-27 #kg
Rad= 637100000.0 #radius planet #cm
g0 = 980.665 #cm/s^2
def g(z):
    return (g0*((Rad/(Rad+z))**2.0))
def scale_height0(z):
    return k*Tm_0(z*10**-5)/(m_Earth_air*mp*g(z))



def functionz(z,zvar):
    return np.exp(-zvar/scale_height0(z))*((Rad+zvar)/(Rad+z))/((np.sqrt(((Rad+zvar)/(Rad+z))**2.0-1.0)))

def chapman0(z):
    return (1.0/(scale_height0(z)))*((integrate.quad(lambda zvar: functionz(z,zvar), z, np.inf))[0])

print chapman0(1000000)
print chapman0(5000000)
```

The first block of variables and definitions are fine. The issue is in the "functionz(z,zvar)" and its integration.
Any help very much appreciated !

Comment: Are you expecting SciPy to solve this analytically? It doesn't do that; the `scipy.integrate` routines all compute numeric approximations.

Comment: What's the value of `m_Earth_air`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It often helps to eliminate possible numerical instabilities by rescaling variables. In your case `zvar` starts from `1e6`, which is probably causing problems due to some implementation details in `quad()`. If you scale it as `y = zvar / z`, so that the integration starts from `1` it seems to converge pretty well for `z = 1e6`:

```
def functiony(z, y):
    return np.exp(-y*z/scale_height0(z))*(Rad+y*z)/(Rad+z) / np.sqrt(((Rad+y*z)/(Rad+z))**2.0-1.0)

def chapman0y(z):
    return (1.0/(scale_height0(z)))*((integrate.quad(lambda y: functiony(z,y), 1, np.inf))[0])

>>> print(chapman0y(1000000))

1.6217257661844094e-06
```

(I set `m_Earth_air = 28.8e-3` — this constant is missing in your code, I assumed it is the molar mass of air in (*edit*) kg/mole).

As for `z = 5e6`, `scale_height0(z)` is negative, which gives a huge positive value under the exponent, making the integral divergent on the infinity.

Comment: Even though it does give out a value now, the issue is still that function(z,y) is infinite when y=1.0, and nan when y=inf. Because of this, the value of the integral is way smaller than it should be. 


Ps. You're right for scale_height0(z), I actually have different scale height functions for different ranges of z, and scale_height0(z) only works for up to 11km (11e5 in my units). 

Ps2. Good guess for m_Earth_air! It was 28.8 kg/kmol, mean molecular weight of air :)

Comment: `quad()` has no problems with infinities when the integral is convergent. You can try to integrate `exp(-x)/sqrt(x)` from `0` to `inf` and you'll get `sqrt(pi)`. There's also nothing improper about your integral. How do you know that the value is smaller than it should be? Wolframalpha integrates it without problems and gives the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you can solve the integral analytically there is no way to solve it without an approximation over its bounds.  This isn't a Python problem, but a calculus problem in general, thus why math classes take such great pains to show you the numeric approximations.

If you don't want it to differ too much, choose a small epsilon with a method that converges fast.

Edit- Clarity on last statement:

Epsilon - ɛ - refers to the step size through the bounds of integration- the delta x-  remember that the numeric approximation methods all slice the integral into slivers and add them back up, think of it as the width of each sliver, the smaller the sliver the better the approximation. You can specify these in numerical packages.

A method that converges fast implies the method approaches the true value of the integral quickly and the error of approximation is small for each sliver.  For example, the Riemann sum is a naive method which assumes each sliver is a rectangle, while a trapezoid connects the beginning and the end of the sliver with a line to make a trapezoid.  Of these 2, trapezoid typically converges faster as it tries to account for the change within the shape. (Neither is typically used as there are better guesses for most functions)

Both of these variables change the computational expense of the calculation.  Typically epsilon is the most expensive to change, thus why it is important you choose a good method of approximation (some can differ by an order of magnitude in error for the same epsilon).

All of this will depend on how much error your calculation can tolerate.

Comment: What method were you thinking about when you said "choose a small epsilon with a method that converges fast" ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and found that SciPy quad needs you to specify another parameter, `epsabs=1e-1000`, `limit=1000` (stepsize limit), `epsrel=1e1` works for everything I've tried.  I.e. in this case:

```
def chapman0(z):    
    return (1.0/(scale_height0(z)))*((integrate.quad(lambda zvar: functionz(z,zvar), z, np.inf, limit=1000, epsabs=1e-1000, epsrel=1e1))[0])[0])
#results:
0.48529410529321887
-1.276589093231806e+21
```

Seems to be a high absolute error tolerance but for integrals that don't rapidly converge it seems to fix the issue.  Just posting for others with similar problems as this post is quite dated.  There are algorithms in other packages that converge faster but none that I've found in SciPy.  The results are based on the posted code (not the selected answer).